# Default Close Operation Changing Nothing

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using the JFreeChart library. The pie chart is a small part of the application, and I'd like to be able to call up the pie chart, close it, and continue using the application. However, right now it closes the whole process, regardless of which WindowConstants.X_ON_CLOSE option I choose:

```
public PieChart(final List<Window> windows) {
    super("Kronos - Window Data");
    final JFreeChart chart = PieChart.createChart(windows);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        final int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        final int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        // this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    });
    final ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    this.setContentPane(panel);
}
```

Comment: What is the super class of `PieChart`? Do you have any links to the source code of JFreeChart?

Comment: All here: https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, if I extend the class by `JFrame` rather than `ApplicationFrame`, works fine. Also `WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` was incorrect, needed `WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE` to hide window without stopping the application.

Hope this helps someone else!